# Name of Hardy Littlewood Lemma/Result

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, riemann-zeta

I am interested in finding the variation of argument of a certain analytic function $g(z)$ on a region of the form $\frac{1}{2}\leq \sigma \leq \sigma_1$, $t_0\leq t \leq T$ where $\sigma$ stands as usual for the real part, and $t$ for the imaginary part.

However, my function has zeros on the line $\sigma=\frac{1}{2}$, $0\leq t \leq T$, and thus I cannot apply the argument theorem. I asked my professor, and he told me that there was a lemma by Hardy and Littlewood if I am not mistaken, that gives a result of the form:

$$2\pi \sum_{\alpha<\sigma_0}(\sigma_0-\alpha)=\int_{t_0}^Tlog|g(\sigma_0+ti)|dt-\int_{\sigma_1}^{\sigma_0}arg(g(\sigma+Ti))d\sigma-\int_{t_0}^Tlog|g(\sigma_1+ti)|dt+\int_{\sigma_1}^{\sigma_0}arg(g(\sigma+t_0i))d\sigma.$$

Where $\sigma_0<\frac{1}{2}$, and the sum is over the $\alpha$, the real parts of the roots of $g(z)$.

However I have not been able to find such a lemma. Does anybody have a reference where I can consult this, or the name of this lemma?

Comment: Integrate by parts $$\Re(\frac{1}{2i\pi}\int_C (s-1/2) \frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}ds)=\sum_{\rho \in C} \Re(\rho)-1/2 $$ $C$ the boundary of a rectangle in the critical strip with no zeros on the boundary, then let $C\to\partial([1/2,\sigma]+i[-T,T])$. Without integration by parts it still holds with the integral on $\Re(s)=1/2$ taken in principal value. Not sure if the real-ness of $\xi(s)$ helps.
You should look at the proofs of the $O(T^a)$ density theorems for the zeros $\Re(s)\in (\sigma,1)$. And you should avoid "a certain analytic functions" in the context of the theory of L-functions

Comment: But my function $g(z)$ is not the Riemann zeta function. I do not see how the left side of your first equality would match with the logarithmic integral of $g$

Comment: Replace $\zeta$ by $g$ and **integrate by parts**. And again avoid "a certain analytic function" if you want your question to make sense in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you are referring to is likely the `Littlewood Argument Principle', also known as the 'Littlewood Lemma'. (I prefer the first name: its abbreviation, LAP, could also be taken as an abbreviation for "Logarithmic Argument Principle" or "Lap Around Perimeter".) It has its origin in:

J. E. Littlewood, On the zeros of the Riemann zeta-function, Mathematical Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society, vol. 22, issue 3, 20 September (1924), pp.  295--318.

It also appears in various forms in:

E. C. Titchmarsh, The Theory of Functions, Oxford University Press, 2nd. edition. [See §3.8]

E. C. Titchmarsh, The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-function, Oxford University Press, 1986, part of the Oxford science publications (Revised second edition by D.R. Heath-Brown, 2007). [See §9.9]

H. Iwaniec, Lectures on the Riemann Zeta Function, American Mathematical Society, 2014, vol. 62 of the University Lecture Series. [See §21]